# 'Discard all changes' has deleted pod files

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

I did a commit on friday, discard all changes on monday, now all my pod related files are in the trash. I realise I probably did something wrong, as I'm quite inexperienced with git etc, but now i really need to restore all my files.

Has anyone come across this before and know what to do?

Comment: How did you discard the changes? With `git stash`, `git clean` or `git reset --hard`?

Comment: Inside xcode, with the button. I feel that was probably my big mistake

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

This should revert your *home directory* to state the state it was prior to those changes you refer to in original post.

**Example**

1. Run `git reflog`
2. Find `HEAD@{ID}` (Ex. `HEAD@{1}`,`HEAD@{2}` etc.) prior to changes that you've made
3. Run `git reset --hard HEAD@{ID}` (`ID` is a number refering to a particular `HEAD` as described in point 2.

**Reference**

[git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

**Useful link**

[Recovering Lost Commits with Git Reflog and Reset](http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits)

Comment: Thanks, tried this, didn't fix it though. The problem seems to have been that Pod files were deleted, that for some reason weren't recovered with this.

Comment: Try to recover to an earlier `HEAD@{id}`. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, incase I ever do this accidentally again (I've done it before), this is what to do.
Basically, it's the pod files that went.

1. Run `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. Add `.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file back, for some reason it was put in the trash when I selected 'Discard All Changes'
3. Run `pod Init`
4. Add details to that file, then run `pod Install`.